# Need help to show output to texbox using Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

The code wont show the total in the textbox I need your help with my code please.

code here:

```
<script>
    function optTotal()
    {
       var a = document.frm.optA.value;
        if (!a)
         a = '0';
         var b = document.frm.optB.value;
        if (!b)
         b = '0';
         var c = document.frm.optC.value;
        if (!c)
         c = '0';
         var d = document.frm.optD.value;
        if (!d)
         d = '0';
        var optA = parseFloat(a);
        var optB = parseFloat(b);
        var optC = parseFloat(c);
        var optD = parseFloat(d);
        document.frm.total.value = optA + optB + optC + optD;
     }
 </script>
```

code here:

```
<form method="post" action="index.php" name="frm" id="frm" >
  <input type="text" name="name" />
  <input type="radio" name="optA" value="1" onclick="optTotal()" />1
  <input type="radio" name="optA" value="2" onclick="optTotal()" />2
  <input type="radio" name="optA" value="3" onclick="optTotal()" />3
  <input type="radio" name="optB" value="1" onclick="optTotal()" />1
  <input type="radio" name="optB" value="2" onclick="optTotal()" />2
  <input type="radio" name="optB" value="3" onclick="optTotal()" />3
  <input type="radio" name="optC" value="1" onclick="optTotal()" />1
  <input type="radio" name="optC" value="2" onclick="optTotal()" />2
  <input type="radio" name="optC" value="3" onclick="optTotal()" />3
  <input type="radio" name="optD" value="1" onclick="optTotal()" />1
  <input type="radio" name="optD" value="2" onclick="optTotal()" />2
  <input type="radio" name="optD" value="3" onclick="optTotal()" />3
  <input type="text" name="total" id="total" onkeyup="optTotal()" />
  <input type="submit" value="enter" name="calculate" />
</form>
```

I want my code to show real time output in the textbox.

Comment: And it is not working because?

Comment: So whats the error you are getting ?

Comment: What *does* your code do compared to what you want it to do?  Do you see any errors in your console?

Comment: My guess is that `document.frm.optA` is selecting *all* of them, not just the selected one.

Comment: my problem is its not working..it wont show up in the textbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Follow the below step**

```
var a1 = document.querySelector('input[name="optA"]:checked');
var b1 = document.querySelector('input[name="optB"]:checked');
var c1 = document.querySelector('input[name="optC"]:checked');
var d1 = document.querySelector('input[name="optD"]:checked');
if (a1 != null)
    a1 = parseFloat(a1.value);
else
    a1 = 0;
if (b1 != null)
    b1 = parseFloat(b1.value);
else
    b1 = 0;
if (c1 != null)
    c1 = parseFloat(c1.value);
else
    c1 = 0;
if (d1 != null)
    d1 = parseFloat(d1.value);
else
    d1 = 0;

document.frm.total.value=parseFloat(a1)+parseFloat(b1)+parseFloat(c1)+parseFloat(d1);
```

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Qd77B/9/)** Click any option of first row, i have modified that for demo

`document.frm.optA` returns the array of nodelist, means all the radio buttons whose names are optA

You have to

```
var a = document.frm.optA  // This will return all radio buttons whoose names are optA
 for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)
 {
       if(a[i].checked)
       {
                alert(a[i].value);
       }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a script to solve your problem, Please have a look.

```
function getCheckedRadio(radio_group) {
        var radio_group = document.getElementsByName(radio_group);
        for (var i = 0; i < radio_group.length; i++) {
            var button = radio_group[i];
            if (button.checked) {
                return button.value;
            }
        }
        return undefined;
    }

   function optTotal()
    {
        var a = getCheckedRadio("optA");// pass radio button group name
        if (!a)
         a = '0';
         var b = getCheckedRadio("optB");// pass radio button group name
        if (!b)
         b = '0';
         var c = getCheckedRadio("optC");// pass radio button group name
        if (!c)
         c = '0';
         var d = getCheckedRadio("optD");// pass radio button group name
        if (!d)
         d = '0';
        var optA = parseFloat(a);
        var optB = parseFloat(b);
        var optC = parseFloat(c);
        var optD = parseFloat(d);
        document.frm.total.value = optA + optB + optC + optD;

     }
```